# Scala implicits for specialization

Tags: scala

I should create class `Example[T]` with 2 different implementations:

1. If `T` can be converted to `Numeric`
2. Another case

I tried to do this with implicit conversion

```
class ExampleImplicits{
  implicit def convert[T](example: Example[T]): ExampleSecond[T] = new ExampleSecond[T]()
}

class Example[T:Numeric]...
class ExampleSecond[T]...
```

I thought that if compiler will not find implicit conversion in `scala.Numeric.Implicit` for T, then he will raise my implicit conversion.

But as I tested code, this works not like this. How can I do this specialization?

---

### UPDATE

What I want to get:

```
val x = new Example[Int]()
x.methodThatHaveOnlyNumerics()
x.methodThatHaveAllImplementations()
val y = new Example[String]()
y.methodThatHaveAllImplementations()
```

Now I can't compile my code.

Comment: Can you show with some example code what you expected to happen and what did happen instead? Because I'm not quite following.

Comment: @Jasper-M thank you for answer, i`ve updated question with expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an implicit class that provides the additional methods in the case that the type parameter is `Numeric`:

```
class Example[X] {
  def methodThatHaveAllImplementations(): Unit = println("all")
}

implicit class ExampleNumOps[N: Numeric](ex: Example[N]) {
  def methodThatHaveOnlyNumerics(): Unit = println("num")
}

val x = new Example[Int]()
x.methodThatHaveOnlyNumerics()
x.methodThatHaveAllImplementations()
val y = new Example[String]()
y.methodThatHaveAllImplementations()
```

Output:

```
num
all
all
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code. And it seems code working as expected. Here object `ob` returns `ExampleSecond[Int]`. I tested with below code.

I hope this is what you expecting.

```
object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val ex = new Example[Int]
        val x = new ExampleImplicits
        val ob = x.convert(ex) // passing Example[Int] object to convert
        println(ob.isInstanceOf[ExampleSecond[Int]]) // returns true because it is of ExaampleSecond[Int] object.
    }

}
class ExampleImplicits {
    implicit def convert[T](example: Example[T]): ExampleSecond[T] = new ExampleSecond[T]()
}

class Example[T: Numeric] {
    println("ex")
}
class ExampleSecond[T] {
    println("ex2")
}

Output :
ex
ex2
true
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Andrey's answer:

```
class Example[T] {
  def methodThatHaveOnlyNumerics()(implicit num: Numeric[T]) = ...

  def methodThatHaveAllImplementations() = ...
}
```